# Spring Update SOAP Header with Two Elements

Tags: java, transform, webservice-client, soapheader, xslt

I am using Spring-WS and WebServiceTemplate to call SOAP WebService.
Currently, i am facing issue while updating SOAP header.

Below is complete structure of SOAP request:

```
<SOAP:envlope>
    <SOAP:Header>
        <Security>
            <username>?</username>
            <password>?</password>
        </Security>
        <MessageData>
            <ClientIP>?</ClientIP>
        </MessageData>
    </SOAP:Header>
    <SOAP:Body>
        <Login/>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:envlope>
```

As shown above, i need to include 2 elements in Header. I have below code to update the Header of SOAP for WebServiceTemplate

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new StringSource(soapHeaderStr), ((SoapMessage) message).getSoapHeader().getResult());
```

But i got below error message when i tried to update header with two elements (String):

**SOAPHeaderString**

```
<Security>
   <username>?</username>
   <password>?</password>
</Security>
<MessageData>
   <ClientIP>?</ClientIP>
</MessageData>
```

**Error**

```
[Fatal Error] :1:197: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
ERROR:  'The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.'
```

The reason is that there is no root element for `Security` and `MessageData` elements and it shouldn't be.

Please help how can i update header in such case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, resolved it !!

I added dummy root while transformation and then removed that dummy root from SOAP Header.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and managed to solve it, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831520/spring-adding-two-elements-to-the-soap-header)

Basically You can marshal the two elements directly into the soap header like this instead of tying to use a Transformer :

```
webServiceTemplate.getMarshaller().marshal(element1,soapHeader.getResult());
webServiceTemplate.getMarshaller().marshal(element2,soapHeader.getResult());
```

The marshaller mentioned here is a "org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" The element 1 and 2 above are the JAXB elements created using the generated Object factory class.