# SOAP Body with Two Elements

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, spring-ws

I am trying to create a soap message with the following structure:

```
<SOAP:Envelope>
    <SOAP:Header/>
    <SOAP:Body>
        <Item1/>
        <Item2/>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I am using a WebServiceMessageCallback to get the above format, but when I try and transform the body with the new source, where source has the above format:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(source, soapBody.getPayloadResult());
```

I get the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:157: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
ERROR:  'The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.'
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransformerException:Transformation error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 157; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.; nested exception is javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 157; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

My understanding is that this error is telling me that the body is not well-formed XML because it doesn't have a single root element.  However, that is what I need as the service I am sending the message to expects the above structure.

Is there some way around this?  Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
I should mention that I have seen [Spring Update SOAP Header with Two Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703646/spring-update-soap-header-with-two-elements), which is what I am trying to do but in the header instead.  I have tried his method of using a dummy root, but I am not sure how to remove the dummy root after the transformation as he mentions.  I don't have enough rep to comment on his answer to find out...

Answer (score 0):

The element `<SOAP:Body>` contains **the** message you want to exchange. Putting in two elements in a `<SOAP:Body>` is therefore not possible. You have to wrap a root XML element around your two items.